# Large file corrupted after commit in git

Tags: git

I created a new git repository on Windows. Then add and commit a single 9.8 GB zip file. The `.git` directory is only 1.21 GB. When I checkout that file, the size is only 1.44 GB.

As far as I know, git does not have a file size limit. Is git broken or there are some limitations? I am using the latest stable release (2.13.0).

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem? Do you still have the original zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - revised estimate of *de facto* size limit

I can confirm that attempting to commit a multi-GB binary file on windows using git 1.12.0.windows.1 I got a corrupt pack file.  I was able to commit and retreive a similar-sized ascii file without any reported errors, but the checked-out file was clearly corrupted (truncated as far as I can tell).

"As far as I can tell", btw, because `diff` (from the bash environment) can't properly handle the larger file.  The cutoff where it starts acting up appears to be in the 2-4GB range.  (That is, a roughly-2GB file works fine - both with git and with diff.  A roughly-4GB file does not.)

What that suggests is that at least some of the processes handling the file have 32-bit limitations.  I would presume that this issue is environmental from git's point of view - that is, a limit of a lib or utility program on which git is depending.

So I would conclude that 4GB may be a *de facto* file size limit, at least on Windows systems.  (Notably my Windows installation is 64-bit; so I suspect the OS itself is not the issue.  But I also don't think the git program itself is the issue.)

At the risk of coming off with a sour-grapes vibe:  Why would you want to do what you've described?  Even if it weren't failing, git would not handle a ~10GB zip file in any useful way.  Large binary files aren't in git's wheelhouse.

You could try using `git lfs`; it helps with several problems git has when dealing with large binary files (though it may fall victim to the same 32-bit limitations if they indeed come from the environment).

Comment: Interesting. I am using 64-bit Windows as well. This 2GB limit is a bit surprising since I get no warnings nor errors when adding/committing the file.

I was thinking about using git to backup all my personal data. That way I could store tens or even hundreds versions of my data while keeping the file size small.

Thanks for the explanation! I will look into `git lfs`.

Comment: I agree the lack of error/warning is troubling, but I do suspect it's because something on which git relies is failing without warning/error and just not passing all the data to git in the first place.  BTW a few more tests suggest that the limit is probably 4GB rather than 2, which makes some sense...

Comment: Regarding git as a backup tool, just be aware that the ways git keeps file size down won't work as well as you might hope if you have binary files that change.  (Essentially git will have to store each version of the file in its entirety.)  Further, be aware that for all the ways LFS helps with this type of file, I don't believe it compresses the data it stores; so the total "repo+LFS store" size may be greater than just a raw git repo.

Comment: Regardless of whether git is *intended* to support this big a file, the fact that it silently corrupts the file is a bug, plain and simple. If git doesn't support this large a file it should refuse to commit it, not corrupt it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree. Failing without warning confuses me a little.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I am aware of that binary might not be stored very efficiently in git repository. Basically what I just wanted to exploit the diff capability of git. I backup all files on my PC every 2 weeks. Let's say the total size is 100GB. 2 weeks later only 1GB of files change. Using git I would only need 101GB to store those 2 versions, instead of 200GB if storing them separately. Compressing is not a concern for me though.

Comment: I've used git to backup my team project folder, which is on google drive and contains a bunch of files that are mostly not code. For every new version, zipping all files (in 'store' mode) and committing the zip works quite well as the file size almost stays constant. I assume in store mode files are not compressed and that would allow diff to work as intended.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - your idealism amuses me.  I doubt git *knows* it's receiving a file that's too large.  I don't know that anyone has suggested it isn't a bug, but if you think you can patch git to fix it, go ahead (and if not, what makes you think the attitude is justified?); git is, after all, open source, no?

Comment: @jetstream96 - And if git suits your needs in that respect, ok.  But you might find you have better luck with a tool that's actually intended for making incremental backups.  (Like you might not stumble onto bugs that apply to your use case but have gone unnoticed because the use case is uncommon for the tool's intended purpose...)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yes I should use a dedicated software for that, but I thought git is more reliable than that ... Maybe I should open a bug report?

Comment: @jetstream96 - Checking git's bug database, and adding a report if there isn't one, couldn't hurt. While I don't know much about the regular maintainers, this seems IMO to be the sort of thing that may not get a lot of priority, but surely it should at least be documented as an issue.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Ok, I will do that.